# What is the tag type of ST M24LR64-R tag

Tags: android, nfc, iso-15693

I am working on NFC based application in Android. I wrote an application which read/write the data from the ST M24LR64-R tag. Application was working fine on Galaxy Nexus. But when we tried the same on Nexus4 or Nexus 10 it seems that they are not detecting the tag. I checked on internet and found that Google has changed the NFC Stack from NXP to broadcom.

Now my question is that NXP generally use either MIFARE Classic 1K or NFC Forum Type2 or Type4 and broadcom uses NFC Forum type 1. So what is the tag type of ST M24LR64-R chip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M24LR64-R is a NfcV Type tag (ISO15693).

The broadcom chip supports this technology. Unfortunately in the NFC software that drives the broadcom chip there is a bug that causes the software to hang if it detects the M24LR64-R.

This problem is known and currently all you can do is to wait for a bugfix.

A lot of other NfcV tags work fine. Unfortunately none of these offer the dual interface that the M24LR64 family offers.